# How to fetch 20 continue number row in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have database like:

```
id  | identifier  | status | content
---------------------------------------
1   |   10       |   AV       | text
2   |   11       |    AV      |  book
3   |   12       |     WK      |  table
4   |    15      |      WK     | test
...
```

I want to get the 20 rows in which all identifier should be continued and status should be 'AV'? How to do it?

I need the identifier is continued like 1,2,3,4,5,6...., so identifier like 1,3,4,5 will not be selected.

I expect result is:

```
id   | identifier |  status  
any  |   101      |    AV
any  |   102      |    AV
any  |   103      |    AV
...
any  |   120      |    AV
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are rows for identifiers 1..20 then I think you may be looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
WHERE status = 'AV'
ORDER BY identifier
LIMIT 20
```

If there are missing identifiers you could left/right join with a sequence of numbers:

```
SELECT Numbers.N, Table1.* FROM Table1 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT N FROM generate_series(1, 20) N) as Numbers
ON Table1.identifier = Numbers.N AND Status = 'AV'
ORDER BY Numbers.N
LIMIT 20
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8a5db/10)

For

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   IDENTIFIER     INT     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   STATUS           TEXT    NOT NULL
   
);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(11123, 1,  'A', 'AV');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(22312, 2,  'B', 'ZB');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1323, 3, 'C', 'AV');
```

the result is

```
n   id  identifier  name    status
1   11123   1   A   AV
2   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
3   1323    3   C   AV
4   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
5   (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

Comment: id is just the primary key, it does not continue. I need the column identifier to continue

Comment: I need identifier contiuned, I will update my expect

Comment: if there is null between 1 and 3 then the identifier 1 will not be select

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: i mean there are lots of numbers in identifier, some of them are consequence, I need to select 20 numbers of identifier and they should be form consequence like 1,2,3,4,5,....20 or 11,12,13,14....30 or 31, 32,33...50

Comment: Change `generate_series(1, 20)` to `generate_series(31, 50)` or whatever is needed...

Answer (score 0):

Use [LIMIT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-limit/) keyword

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT TN.*
FROM YouTableName AS TN
ORDER BY TN.identifier ASC   -- or DESC depending of order wanted
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I need the identifier is continued like 1,2,3,4,5,6...., so identifier like 1,3,4,5 will not selected

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be same as this one:

```
select * 
from tableA 
where status = 'AV'
order by identifier
limit 20
```

`order by` is using `asc` as default so you don't need to set `asc` for this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
Select T1.* from Tablename T1
inner join tablename T2 on (T1.identifier) = (T2.identifier -1)    
where status = 'AV'
union
Select T2.* from Tablename T1
inner join tablename T2 on (T1.identifier) = (T2.identifier -1)  
where status = 'AV'
) Res limit 20
```

Comment: I can see it continued for only 2, how to make sure the 20 numbers limit all continue? I mean your result many contain idetnifier 1,2,4,5

Comment: can you please show the output which you are getting from my query?

Comment: just put the column name instead of * and check the output. Use only column which you want in result,  means id, identifier and status

Comment: the result is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/33b3a/1, I need identifier is continue 20 times. not just one continue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` to get the 20th pretty easily:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(identifier, 19) over (partition by status order by identifier) as prev19_status_identifier
      from t
     ) t
where prev19_status_identifer = identifier - 19 and
      status = 'AV';
```

If you want all such rows, you can treat this as a gaps-and-islands, using:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by status, identifier - seqnum) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by status order by identifier) as seqnum
            from t
            where status = 'AV'
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt >= 20;
```