# fetch N consequence number in a row in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have database like:

```
id  | identifier  | status | content
---------------------------------------
0   |    3       |   AV      |  teth
1   |   10       |   AV       | text
2   |   11       |    AV      |  book
3   |   12       |    WK      |  table
4   |    15      |     WK     | test
...
```

I want to get the 20 rows in which all identifier should be continued and status should be 'AV'? How to do it?

I need the identifier is continued like 1,2,3,4,5,6...., so identifier like 1,3,4,5 will not be selected.

I expect result is:

```
id   | identifier |  status  
any  |   101      |    AV
any  |   102      |    AV
any  |   103      |    AV
...
any  |   120      |    AV
```

I already ask similar question yesterday, but no one give me good answer.
[How to fetch 20 continue number row in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276896/how-to-fetch-20-continue-number-row-in-postgresql)

Comment: If you are going to ask a new question that duplicates another question, you should clearly explain why the answers do not work.  I'm pretty sure the question was answered the first time around.  And if not, you need to explain why the answers do not work -- preferably on the original question.

Comment: in the previous question answers lots of they using 'limit' in order to give the top N, I think I do not give good example of table to make them think they can just return top record. Another stuff is lots of answered the column 'identifier' is not continued which what I want.